# JQuery: Multiple getJSON requests, second does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a Javascript/JQuery script that makes multiple getJSON requests to different APIs, which goes something like this:

```
  var BTC_Value = 0;
  var LTC_Value = 0;

  var loadCoinValues = function()
  {
      $.getJSON( "http://data.mtgox.com/api/2/BTCUSD/money/ticker_fast", function( info ) {
       BTC_Value = info.data['last_local']['value'];
      });

      $.getJSON( "https://btc-e.com/api/2/ltc_usd/ticker", function( info ) {
       LTC_Value = info.ticker['avg'];
      });
     };

  loadCoinValues();

  $("h1").text(BTC_Value); //This returns the correct value.
  $("h2").text(LTC_Value); //This returns nothing.
```

Why does the second getJSON not display a value? Is there a rule I do not know about affecting the results of my code?

Comment: These calls are asynchronous but you seem to assume that they're synchronous in your code.

Comment: I was wondering about that. When do they run? What's the problem? I'm a bit of a noobie to jQuery & Javascript so please bear with me :)

Comment: you have to do the text() calls within the callbacks, where you are setting the BTC_Value and LTC_Value, the callbacks run when the ajax call has completed, if no error.

Comment: It's all about timing in life!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.getJSON` is an asynchronous call. You should do something like this instead:

```
$.getJSON(... ,function(info) {
  $('h1').text(info.data['last_local']['value']);
});
```

When you do `$('h1').text(BTC_Value);` `BTC_Value` doesn't have the value you want yet.
When the AJAX request completets it does, but not before.

Comment: that certainly sounds good, but it's not working for me. Look here: http://jsfiddle.net/43kkS/

Comment: @Burrito411 - You also have another issue. `XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://btc-e.com/api/2/ltc_usd/ticker. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: @Burrito411 - You will need to look up JSON/JSONP

Comment: @Burrito411 Also, learn to use your browser's developer tools (usually F12)

Comment: Thanks! I will be looking into JSONp!